# How can I remove items from my list in my UWP application?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am fairly new to both C# and XAML but I need to create a UWP app for my school project. What I have is basically a simple database for furnitures. I can add items to my list without a problem and I can also list those items, or search in the list, but when I try to remove one I always get this error:
`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

I am using MVVM technology, which I think is the problem, I don't understand it fully. Here's what I have:

```
public class ItemManager
    {
        public readonly CategoryList Categories = new CategoryList();
        public readonly FurnitureList Furnitures = new FurnitureList();
```

This is just a basic item manager, which has the `Furnitures` list, the `FurnitureList` is an `ObservableCollection`.

I have 2 ViewModels, which are:

```
public class ListItemViewModel : ObservableObjectBase
    {

        public Furniture Model { get; private set; }

        public ListItemViewModel(Furniture model)
        {
            Model = model;
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }

        public ListItemViewModel()
        {

        }

        private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.FurnitureID) || e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.Description) || e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.Quantity))
            {
                Notify(nameof(FurnitureToShow));
                Notify(nameof(FurnitureIDAndCategory));
                Notify(nameof(FurnitureDescription));
                Notify(nameof(FurnitureQuantityToDisplay));
            }
            if(e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.Category))
            {
                Notify(nameof(IsSensitive));
            }
        }
```

Here the `FurnitureToShow` and the others are just strings, I believe they are not relevant here.
Here's the other ViewModel (I'm getting the error in this one)

```
 public class ListViewModel : ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>
    {
        public ListViewModel(FurnitureList model)
        {
            model.CollectionChanged += Model_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void Model_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
                foreach (Furniture f in e.NewItems)
                    this.Add(new ListItemViewModel(f));
            if(e.OldItems != null)
            {
                var toRemove = this.Items.Where(i => e.OldItems.Contains(i.Model));
                foreach (var vm in toRemove)    **This is the line where the error pops up**
                    this.Remove(vm);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I select an item from a ListView, I press the delete button and the selected item gets deleted from the original collection. Here's the XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView SelectionChanged="ItemGotSelected_Filter"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind selectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedIndex="{x:Bind selectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
        x:Name="FilteredListView"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True" 
        Height="500"
        Width="230"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>

        <StackPanel Width="170">
            <TextBlock Margin="8,8,8,4" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">Filter by...</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="FilterByID" Width="150" Header="Furniture ID" Margin="8"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextChanged="OnFilterChanged"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="FilterByCategory" Width="150" Header="Category" Margin="8"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextChanged="OnFilterChanged"/>
            <Button Margin="8,20,8,4" x:Name="deleteButton" Width="80" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Content="Delete item" FontSize="14" Padding="1" IsEnabled="False" Click="deleteButton_Click">
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

I am pretty sure the binded SelectedItem represents the actual Furniture item I would like to delete, but correct me if I'm wrong. So finally here's the C# code behind:

```
public sealed partial class ThreeLineList : UserControl
    {
        public FurnitureList allFurnitures;

        public ListViewModel AllFurnituresList { get; private set; }

        public Furniture selectedItem = null;
        public int selectedIndex;

        private ObservableCollection<Furniture> filteredFurnitures = new ObservableCollection<Furniture>();

        public ThreeLineList()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetModel(ItemManager itemManager)
        {            
            this.allFurnitures = itemManager.Furnitures;
            this.AllFurnituresList = new ListViewModel(allFurnitures);
            this.filteredFurnitures = new ObservableCollection<Furniture>(allFurnitures);            

            FilteredListView.ItemsSource = filteredFurnitures;
        }

        private void ItemGotSelected_Filter(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            deleteButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            allFurnitures.Remove(selectedItem);
            //filteredFurnitures.Remove(selectedItem);            
        }
```

The `filteredFurnitures` and everything that has to do with Filters is not relevant, that part is working perfectly so I didn't include it. So in my head I have the items in my ListView that are actually in the original list, since the `allFurnitures` list is connected to the item manager, and if I add items to the list using another View, they appear correctly. That's the reason I don't understand why do I get an error message, when I try to delete the selected item from that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumeration (such as in a foreach loop) is sequential. When you delete an element, you break the sequence which can cause an "index out of range" exception. Use a for loop instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot believe I did not notice it. I managed to extremely overcomplicate the problem. I am really grateful!

Comment: @armin_somogyi if this helped you, why not mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Just learning how to use this site properly, apologies!